# Read gzip stream line by line

Tags: node.js, gzip, zlib

I've got a compressed gzip file which I would like to read line by line.

```
var fs = require('fs')
var zlib = require('zlib')
var gunzip = zlib.createGunzip()
var inp = fs.createReadStream('test.gz')
var n = 0

var lineProcessing = function (err, data) {
    if (!err) {
        n += 1
        console.log ("line: " + n)
        console.log (data.toString())
    }
}

inp
  .on('data', function (chunk) {
      zlib.gunzip (chunk, lineProcessing)
  })
  .on('end', function () {
    console.log ('ende');
  });
```

I guess I need to set a chunksize for `zlib.createGunzip` that I only read until the next `\n`. But how to determine it dynamically?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It might be easier to use [`readline`](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) for this:

```
const fs       = require('fs');
const zlib     = require('zlib');
const readline = require('readline');

let lineReader = readline.createInterface({
  input: fs.createReadStream('test.gz').pipe(zlib.createGunzip())
});

let n = 0;
lineReader.on('line', (line) => {
  n += 1
  console.log("line: " + n);
  console.log(line);
});
```

Comment: What about if I want to stream unzipped stream form another function instead of unzipping local file? I get some weird errors coming from readline.js file..

Comment: @Tomas do you mean you want to process a "regular" stream (not a gzipped one)? You can use any readable stream as argument for `input`.

Comment: I'm trying to use a stream coming from zlib.gunzip(). my work flow is: I get file from aws s3, unzip it using gunzip, then pass the stream to readline but it's throwing me errors, could it be that stream is inconsistent or something?

Comment: Apparently once I unzip file using gunzip it passes not a stream but a string.

Comment: @Tomas `zlib.gunzip()` doesn't return a stream, it returns the gunzipped data (in the callback). You probably want to use `zlib.createGunzip()` as well.

Comment: I tried doing `data.pipe(zlib.createGunzip())` `data` being gunzipped buffer coming from `zlib.gunzip()` and I get an error saying that `data.pipe(zlib.createGunzip()) is not a function` any ideas on this?

Comment: @Tomas perhaps open a new question where you explain what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: would you mind having a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38120231/how-to-gunzip-stream-in-nodejs) ?

Answer (score 10):

If anyone is still looking into how to do this years later, and wants a solution that works with `async`/`await`, here's what I'm doing (TypeScript, but you can just ditch the type annotations).

```js
import fs from "fs";
import zlib from "zlib";
import readline from "readline";

const line$ = (path: string) => readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream(path).pipe(zlib.createGunzip()),
    crlfDelay: Infinity
});

const yourFunction = async () => {
    for await (const line of line$("/path/to/file.txt.gz")) {
        // do stuff with line
    }
}
```

Comment: `TypeError: line$(...) is not a function or its return value is not async iterable`

Comment: What runtime are you using? I have Node `v14.4.0`.

Answer (score 5):

Read plain text or gzip files line by line, in TypeScript:

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as zlib from 'zlib'
import * as readline from 'readline'

function readFile(path: string) {
    let stream: NodeJS.ReadableStream = fs.createReadStream(path)
    
    if(/\.gz$/i.test(path)) {
        stream = stream.pipe(zlib.createGunzip())
    }

    return readline.createInterface({
        input: stream,
        crlfDelay: Infinity
    })
}

async function main() {
    const lineReader = readFile('/usr/share/man/man1/less.1.gz')

    for await(const line of lineReader) {
        console.log(line)
    }
}

main().catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(1)
})
```